# Java Serversocket refuses connection even when queue is not full

Tags: java, networking, serversocket, connectexception

Hi I am trying to set up a ServerSocket in java and I have kept the backlog level to default 50. I have 5 clients trying to connect to the server at almost the same time. Sometimes everything goes smoothly while sometimes some of the client's connections are refused by the server. I have tried increasing backlog value to 100 but no luck. I am using Ubuntu 13.10. Any ideas?

```
package networkmodule;

import iomodule.FileHandler;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileReceiveServer implements Runnable {

private ServerSocket server;
private int receiveport;
private boolean isMaster;
private boolean isStats;
private ArrayList<Thread> clientThreads;
private int totalClients;
private int clientsReceived;

public FileReceiveServer(int receiveport, boolean isMaster, boolean isStats) {
    this.receiveport = receiveport;
    this.isMaster = isMaster;
    this.isStats = isStats;
    clientThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    if (isMaster && !isStats) {
        totalClients = ((Hashtable<String, String>) FileHandler.loadObject("clientstats")).size();
        clientsReceived = 0;
    }
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(receiveport);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
            Thread newClientThread = new Thread(new FileReceiverThread(clientSocket, isMaster, isStats));
            clientThreads.add(newClientThread);
            newClientThread.start();
            if (isMaster && !isStats) {
                clientsReceived++;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

public boolean checkThreadCompletion() {
    if (isMaster) {
        if (clientsReceived < totalClients) {
            return false;
        }
        if (clientThreads.size() > 0) {
            for (Thread t : clientThreads) {
                if (t != null) {
                    if (t.isAlive()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        if (clientThreads.size() > 0) {
            for (Thread t : clientThreads) {
                if (t != null) {
                    if (t.isAlive()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public void stopServer() {
    try {
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is quite a simple code and I have no idea why it fails sometimes. Here the important thing is that it fails only sometimes not always, and when it fails, it always fails on client side when I try to make a socket to connect to the server with:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Socket Connection Refused
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more information? Code snippets? As it stands this question is really hard to answer.

Comment: The platform can adjust the backlog you supply up or down, and there is no way to determine the actual backlog value. Do you really get 'connection refused' or is it sometimes some other error?

Comment: You've got an ignored exception there. Put some proper exception handling in there and retry. At least print the stack trace. You can *never* just ignore an `IOException.`

Comment: @EJP I can assure you that is not the reason. You see I intend to shut down the server once I know all the clients have replied back. In this case printing the stack trace would just serve to cluster the output as the exception will always be caught. I get the exception when the client is trying to connect. I figured out a workaround in the client where I reconnect every 10 ms until the server accepts the connection, but the main question still remains unanswered. If the default backlog value is 50 and I have just 5 clients connecting to the server, why does it refuse connections sometimes?

Comment: I've already answered every particle of that. You can't know what an exception actually is unless you log it or print it somehow. You can't know what the actual backlog is, so you don't have any grounds for believing that it is 50. Amend your program to handle exceptions properly; re-test; and amend your question according to the actual results and exceptions you actually get. Your guesswork about whether an exception is significant or not is of no interest. If you were right about everything you wouldn't have a problem, and you wouldn't be posting here.